# Create Fitness score/highscore with multiple variables

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms

I am currently building a Neural network( + genetic algorithms) that learns to fly a 2D drone to a target.
My goal is that it achieve all tasks as fast a possible but I want the drone to also fly stable and upright. the way I tried to calculate fitness was to create a function that has the greatest value when the drone does everything I want right.

`fitness += 1/distToTarget + cos(drone_angle)`

my current inputs are:

```
difference_target_X
difference_target_Y
velocity_X
velocity_Y
angular_velocity (degree per second)
drone_angle     | = 0;     |_ = 90     _| = -90
```

output (i don't think it is important but:)

```
left_thruster_angle
left_thruster_boost
right_thruster_angle
right_thruster_boost
```

The NN is programed in unity and the drone uses a 2D Rigidbody and the NN adds a force to the thruster at the right angle.

How do I get the drone to set the best weights to fulfill all tasks: `fly stable, fly fast, fly to the target`?

thanks in advance

Comment: "My goal is that it archives all tasks" Why **archive** the tasks?

Comment: my bad - achieve*